# obtain the probability equation represented by plotmo plots

Tags: r, glm

I want to obtain the equations of the probability functions represented by plotmo (R). This is the equations of the model when varying one or two predictors while holding the other predictors constant in the mean value. I want an easy way to obtain the mathematical equation because a must to make to many models with different variables.

if my model is like this:

```
glm(formula = pres_aus ~ pH_sp + Annual_prec + I(pH_sp^2) + I(Annual_prec^2), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = puntos_calibrado)
```

how can i make it?

Comment: Is `plotmo` a function? If so, what package? If this is a request for an explanation of the mathematics of logistic regression, it is off-topic here and you should ask for migration to CrossValidated.com

Comment: Plotmo is a function inside the package plotmo.  My question is not about the mathematics behind logistic regression. Plotmo plots the logistic regresion varying one predictor while holding the other predictors constant in the mean value. i just want to obtain the resulting equation of that.

Comment: if you initially (in the simplest way) have Y=aX+bZ+cW (capital letters are the variables), then (varying one predictor while holding the other predictors constant in the mean value) you will have Y= aX+(bZ+cW) where therms between brakets are a constant. plotmo plots the response curve of this, but never shows you the equation because his procedure to obtain the curve is diferent.

Answer (score 0):

No data example provided, so no testing done,  but couldn't you just skip the construction of a symbolic expression and do something along the lines of:

```
model.matrix(data.frame(one=1, dat) ) %*% coef(mdl.fit) 
# where mdl.fit is returned from glm()
```

In a sense this is the R matrix representation of the formula: sum( beta_i*X_1). If you want to specify a mean value for a particular column then just pull that dataframe apart and use only parts of it for a calculation. So for the first column held at the mean:

```
model.matrix(data.frame(one=1, mn1 =mean(dat[[1]]), dat[-1]) ) %*% 
                                                       coef(mdl.fit)
```